# Little clarification required in integrals of multiple variable

Tags: multivariable-calculus, divergence-theorem

How is this integral: $$\iint_{S} p(x,y,z)\,dy\,dz + q(x,y,z)\,dz\,dx + r(x,y,z)\,dx\,dy$$
equivalent to this one
$$ \iint_S \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{S}$$ where $\vec{F}=\left<p,q,r\right>$

(I was trying to solve a question on Divergence theorem and spent too much time trying to find what is $\vec{F}$ and then peeked into the solution to find the above which was right in front of me the whole time)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Well, those are usually different notations for the same thing.

Comment: Heuristically you can say $dydz \leftrightarrow n_x dS$

Comment: In case you are interested, what @NinadMunshi said is made rigorous and proven in chapter 13.8 of the great book *Analysis II* by Konrad Königsberger. (Sadly, I am only able to find a German edition .)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second version is what I call the “20th-century” notation for the surface integral.  The definition is:
$$
   \iint_S \vec F \cdot d \vec S = \iint_S \vec F \cdot \vec n \,dS
$$
where $\vec n$ is a unit normal vector field on $S$.

To compute this integral, we normally need a parametrization.  Suppose that $D$ is a domain of $\mathbb R^2$, and $\vec r \colon D \to S$ is a parametrization of $S$ compatible with the orientation $\vec n$.  Write $\vec r(u,v) = (x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v))$.  We define
\begin{align*}
    \vec r_u &= \left<\frac{\partial x}{\partial u},\frac{\partial y}{\partial u},\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\right>
\\  \vec r_v &= \left<\frac{\partial x}{\partial v},\frac{\partial y}{\partial v},\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\right>
\end{align*}
Then $\vec r$ is compatible with $\vec n$ if $\vec r_u \times \vec r_v$ is in the positive direction of $\vec n$ for all $(u,v) \in D$. In this case,
$$
   \iint_S \vec F \cdot \vec n \,dS
   = \iint_D \vec F(\vec r(u,v)) \cdot (\vec r_u \times \vec r_v)\,dA
$$
Let's take it one step further down.  Write $\vec F(x,y,z) = \left<P(x,y,z),Q(x,y,z),R(x,y,z)\right>$.  Then
$$
\vec r_u \times \vec r_v
    = \left<\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \frac{\partial z}{\partial v}
           -\frac{\partial z}{\partial u} \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}, 
           \frac{\partial z}{\partial u} \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}
           -\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \frac{\partial z}{\partial v},
           \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
           -\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}
    \right>
$$
So
\begin{align*}
\iint_D \vec F(\vec r(u,v)) \cdot (\vec r_u \times \vec r_v)\,dA
    &= \iint_D \biggl(
         P(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v))
         \left(
            \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \frac{\partial z}{\partial v}
           -\frac{\partial z}{\partial u} \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} 
         \right)
     \\&\qquad\qquad+
         Q(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v))
         \left(
            \frac{\partial z}{\partial u} \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}
           -\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \frac{\partial z}{\partial v} 
         \right)
     \\&\qquad\qquad+
         R(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v))
         \left(
            \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
           -\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} 
         \right)
      \biggr)\,du\,dv\tag{$*$}
\end{align*}

In order to understand the “19th-century” notation:
$$
    \iint_S \left(P \,dy\,dz + Q \,dz\,dx + R \,dx\,dy\right)
$$
you just have to treat the $dx$, $dy$, $dz$ symbols as differentials, compute them in terms of $du$ and $dv$, and assume that differentials can be multiplied *skew-commutatively*. So:
\begin{align*}
    dx &= \frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\,du + \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\,dv \\
    dy &= \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\,du + \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\,dv \\
    dz &= \frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\,du + \frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\,dv
\end{align*}
and therefore,
\begin{align*}
    dy\,dz &= 
     \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\,du + \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\,dv\right)
     \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\,du + \frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\,dv\right)
    \\&= \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\frac{\partial z}{\partial u} \,du\,du
      + \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\,du\,dv
      + \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\,dv\,du
      +\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\,dv\,dv
    \\&= \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \frac{\partial z}{\partial v}
    - \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\right)\,du\,dv
\end{align*}
(Notice $du\,du = dv\,dv = 0$, and also $dv\,du = -du\,dv$, by skew-commutativity.)
You see that this is the same combination of partial derivatives that forms the $x$-component of $\vec r_u \times \vec r_v$.  Similarly,
\begin{align*}
    dz\,dx &= \left(            \frac{\partial z}{\partial u} \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}
           -\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \frac{\partial z}{\partial v} 
\right)\,du\,dv
\\  dy\,dy &= \left(            \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
           -\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} 
\right)\,du\,dv
\end{align*}
So $    \iint_S \left(P \,dy\,dz + Q \,dz\,dx + R \,dx\,dy\right)$ turns out to be equal to the right-hand side of ($*$) as well.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts to explain @matthew